# AgGrid onPaginationChanged differentiate between onload and pagination button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using AgGrid and have passed onPaginationChanged={onPaginationChanged} to the AgGrid component.

Now this onPaginationChanged handler gets invoked even on the AgGrid load and so I am unable to differentiate in the handler during onload and when the actual pagination buttons are clicked.

is there any way to identify this difference as I need to write some logic only if the onPaginationChanged handler is called during pagination button click?

Just to add, I am using "ag-grid-community" v25.0.0" and I get params as undefined inside onPaginationChanged handler.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-pagination

onPaginationChanged event has a parameter called newPage which is of type boolean

```
const onPaginationChanged = useCallback((event) => {
  console.log('onPaginationPageLoaded', event);
}, []);
```

[image: onPaginationChanged event]

Yes, onPaginationChanged gets invoked on AgGrid load but in this case newPage parameter is false. If you change your current page, event gets triggered and in this time our newPage parameter is true. This is what you're looking for I guess.

Check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/GaO2r78uGN82X9Bl?preview

Comment: Thanks...I tried the above...getting event as undefined in both cases...load and next click

Comment: I need to see your code